# What was Cheddar Bob's last name?

Tags: character, 8-mile

This refers to the character of [Cheddar Bob](http://8mile.wikia.com/wiki/Cheddar_Bob), played by actor [Evan Jones](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0428055/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t5) in the seminal 2002 musical drama *[8 Mile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8_Mile_(film))* starring rapper Eminem as Jimmy "B-Rabbit" Smith Jr.

Do we know what his last name was? Does he even have one? I've been searching on-line and on IMDB, but can find an answer. Wondering if it ever came up in the dialogue.

Comment: I liked the movie 8-Mile, I really did, but in what way is it [seminal](https://www.google.ca/search?q=seminal&rlz=1C1OCLT_enCA757CA757&oq=seminal&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4992j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: @Steve-O I see it as a cultural reference point, moreso even than the Fast&Furious franchise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

His last name was Zurowsky.  There's a scene where Eminem gets into a fight with his mom's boyfriend, who happens to be about the same age as Eminem.  The exchange goes something like this:

> Eminem's mom: Baby, are you staying here for a while or what?
>
> Eminem: Just for a couple weeks, till l can save enough to get my own place.
>
> Mom's boyfriend: Just like Bob Zurowsky.  All your friends still
> living at home, aren't they?  What a bunch of *** losers.